# Building an ORM and debating setters vs builders

Tags: java, design-patterns, orm, builder, setter

I am trying to build an ORM around GlideRecords. GlideRecords have a format similar to

```
var inc = new GlideRecord('incident');
inc.addQuery("foo", "1");
inc.addQuery("bar", "1");
inc.query();
```

The orm is intended to look like this:
`var inc = new ORM().foo("1").bar("1").query();`

My immediate decision was to implement the ORM using `builder pattern` but then realized that I also had to support `update` operations.
ie

`inc.foo("2").update()`

Now update needs me to use `setters`

So Help me chose from following options:

1. Use only setters
2. Use builders and setters.

Answer (score 0):

You also have another option. Look at those two interfaces:

- [`Frozen`](https://github.com/fge/btf/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/Frozen.java);
- [`Thawed`](https://github.com/fge/btf/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/Thawed.java).

With this, if you make `ORM implements Frozen<ORMBuilder>` and `ORMBiilder implements Thawed<ORM>` you can do:

```
// "orm" is an ORM instance
orm.thaw().foo("2").freeze().update();
```

Basically, these two interfaces allow you to "rebuild a builder" out of a frozen value.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how [JPA does things](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html) for setting parameters. It allows method chaining for the builder pattern, and it works out rather well.